# cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<ApplicationRoleManager> in asp mvc identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2

this code for create a role in database .

IdentityConfig:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(RoleStore<IdentityRole> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(roleStore);
    }
}
```

but in Startup.Auth show me error :

[image]

How can I solve this error ?

**Edit**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

Comment: I see your error comes from auth configuration, please show any relevant codes on `ConfigureAuth` method inside identity `Startup` class.

Comment: update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature for `CreatePerOwingContext<T>` looks like this:

```
public static IAppBuilder CreatePerOwinContext<T>(this IAppBuilder app, Func<IdentityFactoryOptions<T>, IOwinContext, T> createCallback) where T : class, IDisposable
```

or like this:

```
public static IAppBuilder CreatePerOwinContext<T>(this IAppBuilder app, Func<T> createCallback) where T : class, IDisposable
```

I.e. you ether need to provide a function that will create you an object, i.e.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(() => new ApplicationRoleManager(/*blah params*/));
```

This will be using second override. Or go back to defaults:

```
public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var applicationDbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(applicationDbContext);
    var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(roleStore);

    return manager;
}
```